# How to open Fedora without a user password?

Tags: fedora, login, autologin

How do I open [Fedora 19](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Fedora_releases#Fedora_19) without a user password?

My user name is *mz2*, and I want to login without a password.

Comment: Hi, could you please try and add a bit more detail to your Q? It's unclear what exactly it is you're looking for.

Comment: Note that this is almost *never* a good idea. Even on a single user machine in your own home.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the passwd man page:

```
-d     This is a quick way to delete a password for an account. It will
          set the named account passwordless. Available to root only.
```

so you can do this (as root):

```
passwd -d mz2
```

then you can login without a password

Comment: @cuonglm's approach below is much better as it does not result in a passwordless profile.

Comment: Passwordless profile is not ideal. Can't ssh into it.

Answer (score 28):

You can do it two ways:

1. Open System Settings => Users => Click icon `Automatic Login`
2. Edit `/etc/gdm/custom.conf`, add theses lines:

> ```
> [daemon]
> AutomaticLoginEnable=true
> AutomaticLogin=mz2
> ```

Comment: In GNOME Shell 3.2 the setting is found under `System Settings --> Details --> Users`

Answer (score 4):

In Gnome, you can follow these steps.

Click ..

1. Activities - Show Applications - Settings - Users.

Here you will see your users details for login.
Make the password - None.
Automatic Login - ON.

Then restart the PC. Problem solved.

Comment: No doesn't work. And you can't make the password empty on latest Fedora

Answer (score 0):

In addition to *Settings -> Users -> Enable Automatic Login*

I also went to *Privacy -> Screen Lock -> Disable Automatic Screen Lock*

Without removing a password from the user account (still needed for sudo/ssh) the computer will automatically login, and stay logged in after the display sleeps.